# Android, Java Socket

Tags: java, php, android

I have created a **TCP socket client** in **android** and use  a open src socket app which i use as a server to send messages to my android app, every thing works fine.

But the doubt is that both device are present using my home wifi connection hence having 192.x.x.x series ip,

But in case my device is connected to wifi router in my home having Ip of 192.x.x.x and server is having static Ip, will my server be able to send message to the **remote device**, irrespective of the fact there the device is having local network Ip ?

Comment: Sure. The router takes care of that. It's called NAT (network address translation) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: Thanks for replying Matjaz Muhic, But I wanna ask, if this works what ip should I give to my server socket to send message, as far as I know, ill get the address of wifi router if I trace, hence sending message, wont work since my phone will have local address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't be able to send data to the remote device unless and untill it initiates the connection , you cannot initiate a connection to a dynamic Ip(remote Device
)